# Parsing the file perl

Tags: linux, perl, parsing

This programme acually prints the $rf_id,$date,$qf_id and $failure_msg into a file, the problem is while getting the first value it stores the value of $rf_id as 0 and rest is the same value is printed as desired.The rf_id is sumhow is getting set to 0 in only firstline in other lines its just fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $mailqdir = "/mail1.txt";
my $mqueue_directory = "/var/spool/mqueue/";
my $messages_removed = 0;
my $rf_id;
my $date;
my $temp;
my $tmp;
my @write_array;
my $to;
my $from;
my $subject;
my $path_to_sendmail = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -f";
my $mailsubject = "Subject: Deleted Queued Mails from LSMGR sendmail \n\n\n";

$ENV{"PATH"}="/usr/sbin/:/usr/sbin";
my $currentfile = `sendmail -bp`;
my $qf_id = 0;
my $failure_msg;
my $qf_file;
my $df_file;

open (MYFILE, ">/queue.txt");
print MYFILE "$currentfile";
close (MYFILE);
system("/etc/init.d/sendmail stop");
open(MYFILE,$mailqdir);
 while (<MYFILE>){
    if(/(?<=<)[^>]+(?=>\s*$)/g){
        $temp=$_;
        $temp =~ s/^\s+|s+$//g;
        $rf_id = "$temp";
        my $tmp = "$temp";
    }
    if (/(\w{14})/){
        $qf_id=$1;
        $qf_file = 'qf' . $1;
        $df_file = 'df' . $1;
        $date = substr($_,24,17);
        next unless /(\w{14})/;
        $temp = scalar <MYFILE>;   
        $temp =~ s/^\s+|s+$//g;
        $failure_msg=$temp;
    }
    push(@write_array,"$qf_file:$failure_msg:$date:$rf_id");
    $ENV{"PATH"}="/var/run/:/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions:/var/lock/subsys/:/etc/init.d/sendmail:/etc/init.d:/bin/:/usr/local/bin/:/var/spool/mqueue";
    print "Removing $qf_file... \n";
    print "Removing $df_file...\n";
    system ("rm $mqueue_directory$qf_file");
    system ("rm $mqueue_directory$df_file");
    $messages_removed++;
}
close (MYFILE);
open (CODE,">/mail.txt");
print CODE "@write_array";
close (CODE);
system("/etc/init.d/sendmail start");
$to='';
$from='';
$ENV{"PATH"}="/usr/sbin/:/usr/sbin";
#system ("$path_to_sendmail $from $to < /mail.txt");
print "\n$messages_removed total \"Deferred Mails\" message(s) removed from ";
print "mail queue.\n";
```

---

This is a type of record i want parse this is one of the example:

```
  q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
q2VDWKkY010408  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
q2VDWKkY010409  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
q2VDWKkY010410  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
```

Comment: You close MYFILE (opened for writing), then you are reading lines from it. Are you sure it works at all?

Comment: Thanks choroba
It was a typo mistake i edited it

Comment: @yagavalkbhatt Please, reduce your code to only keep the lines neccessary to reproduce the problem. Copy-paste the exact code so we can run it and fix it.

Comment: Thanks chorobo this is the whole code and and for some reason its not printing the first value of $rf_id,instead code is printing 0 and rest of the things it prints fine ,only in first record in mail.txt its printing 0 and from second line its printing the required $rf_id.

Comment: This is not the code. There is a syntax error (`{` instead of `;` after `open`).

Comment: Thanks choroba
thanks for ur patience ,i have looked into the code again and edited it

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. After simplifying and fixing (no lookaround needed, missing backslash before `s` in substitution) your code to

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $temp;
my $rf_id;
my $failure_msg;
my $messages_removed;
my @write_array;

while (<DATA>){
    chomp;
    if(/<[^>]+>\s*$/g){
        $temp  = $_;
        $temp  =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
        $rf_id = $temp;
    }
    my ($qf_file, $df_file, $date);
    if (/^(\w{14})/){
        $qf_file = 'qf' . $1;
        $df_file = 'df' . $1;
        $date = substr $_, 24, 17;
        next unless /(\w{14})/;
        $temp =  scalar <DATA>;
        $temp =~ s/^\s+|s+$//g;
        $failure_msg = $temp;
    }
    push(@write_array,"$qf_file:$failure_msg:$date:$rf_id\n");
    print "rm $qf_file $df_file\n";
    $messages_removed++;
}

print "\n\nCODE\n@write_array\n";
print "\n$messages_removed total \"Deferred Mails\" message(s) removed from ";
print "mail queue.\n";

__DATA__
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
q2VDWKkY010408  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
q2VDWKkY010409  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
q2VDWKkY010410  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
```

I am getting this output:

```
rm qfq2VDWKkY010407 dfq2VDWKkY010407
Use of uninitialized value $qf_file in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 29, <DATA> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $date in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 29, <DATA> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $qf_file in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 30, <DATA> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $df_file in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 30, <DATA> line 3.
rm  
rm qfq2VDWKkY010408 dfq2VDWKkY010408
Use of uninitialized value $qf_file in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 29, <DATA> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $date in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 29, <DATA> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $qf_file in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 30, <DATA> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $df_file in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 30, <DATA> line 6.
rm  
rm qfq2VDWKkY010409 dfq2VDWKkY010409
Use of uninitialized value $qf_file in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 29, <DATA> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $date in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 29, <DATA> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $qf_file in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 30, <DATA> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $df_file in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 30, <DATA> line 9.
rm  
rm qfq2VDWKkY010410 dfq2VDWKkY010410
Use of uninitialized value $qf_file in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 29, <DATA> line 12.
Use of uninitialized value $date in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 29, <DATA> line 12.
Use of uninitialized value $qf_file in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 30, <DATA> line 12.
Use of uninitialized value $df_file in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 30, <DATA> line 12.
rm  


CODE
qfq2VDWKkY010407:(host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
:Sat Mar 31 19:37 :q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
 :(host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
::<yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
 qfq2VDWKkY010408:(host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
:Sat Mar 31 19:37 :q2VDWKkY010408  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
 :(host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
::<yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
 qfq2VDWKkY010409:(host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
:Sat Mar 31 19:37 :q2VDWKkY010409  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
 :(host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
::<yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
 qfq2VDWKkY010410:(host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
:Sat Mar 31 19:37 :q2VDWKkY010410  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
 :(host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
::<yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>


8 total "Deferred Mails" message(s) removed from mail queue.
```

Please, try to explain what you are trying to achieve. When running code, please pay attention to the warnings you are getting - you are running `rm` (which could be replaced by Perl's `unlink`) on an empty filename.

**Update:** Wildly guessing what you might be up to:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %matched;
my @out;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^(?<id>\S{14})\s+
          (?<num>[0-9]+)\s+
          (?<day>...)\s+
          (?<month>...)\s+
          (?<monthday>[0-9]+)\s+
          (?<time>[0-9]+:[0-9]+)\s+
         <(?<from>.*)>/x) {
        %matched = %+;

    } elsif (/^\s+<(.*)>/) {
        $out[-1] .= ":$1";

    } elsif (s/^\s+\(/(/) {
        print "rm qf$matched{id} df$matched{id}\n";
        push @out, join ':', "qf$matched{id}",
                              $_,
                              join ' ',@matched{qw/day month monthday time/};

    } else {
        die "Cannot parse: $_\n";
    }
}

print "$_\n" for @out;
print scalar @out, " messages removed.\n";

__DATA__
q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
q2VDWKkY010408  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
q2VDWKkY010409  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
q2VDWKkY010410  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <Mailer-daemon>
                     (host map: lookup (my.local.domain): deferred)
                                             <yagyavalkbhatt@yahoo.com>
```

Note that `:` as a delimiter is probably not the best choice: it is used in time and twice in the message, too.

Comment: Thanks choroba 
While running your code i got this error "sequence not recognize in perl regex"

Comment: Basically i want to parse the file in this format $date:$qf_id:$failure_msg:rf_id in to a new file and send that file in a mail,while deleting files from mqueue directory with there $qf_id,thats the main porpose of this code

Comment: @yagyavalkbhatt: You probably have an ancient version of Perl.