# print lines below the matching line

Tags: linux, perl

Currently I am greping 3rd line from matching pattern. In this case `q33BDrP9007220` is a matching pattern and 3rd line will be printed, I want to print 4th and 5th line as well, but only if the pattern of 4th and 5th line matches the 3rd line pattern.And print those 3 email ids in one line separated by ','.

```
open (MYFILE,<$mailqdir);
while(<MYFILE>)
if(/(\w{14})/){
next unless \w{14})/ % 2;
$temp = scalar <MYFILE>;
$rf_id = $temp;
}
```

--------------Input-----------------

```
q33BDrP9007220    50153 Tue Apr  3 16:43 <mohitnegi@yahoo.com>
                 (Deferred: 451 4.2.1 mailbox temporarily disabled: paond.tndt)
                                         <tarunsharma@yahoo.com>
                                         <tararma@yahoo.com>
                                         <tarsharma@yahoo.com>
q33BDrP9007220    50153 Tue Apr  3 16:43 <mohitnegi@yahoo.com>
                 (Deferred: 451 4.2.1 mailbox temporarily disabled: paond.tndt)
                                         <tnsharma@yahoo.com>
                                         <tama@yahoo.com>
                                         <harma@yahoo.com>
q33BDrP9007220    50153 Tue Apr  3 16:43 <mohitnegi@yahoo.com>
             (Deferred: 451 4.2.1 mailbox temporarily disabled: paond.tndt)
                                     <tarunrma@yahoo.com>
                                     <taarma@yahoo.com>
                                     <tsharma@yahoo.com>
```

Comment: possible [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877118/putting-2-consecutive-lines-of-same-matching-pattern-into-single-line) . I guess,it's near to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example might help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @emails;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^\w{14}\s/) {
        <DATA>;              # skip one line
        output(@emails);
        undef @emails;       # forget emails
    } elsif (/^\s+<([^>]+)>$/) {
        push @emails, $1;    # remember the email
    }
}

# Print the last rememberd emails
output(@emails);

sub output {
    print join(',', @_), "\n" if @_;
}

__DATA__
q33BDrP9007220    50153 Tue Apr  3 16:43 <mohitnegi@yahoo.com>
                 (Deferred: 451 4.2.1 mailbox temporarily disabled: paond.tndt)
                                         <tarunsharma@yahoo.com>
                                         <tararma@yahoo.com>
                                         <tarsharma@yahoo.com>
q33BDrP9007220    50153 Tue Apr  3 16:43 <mohitnegi@yahoo.com>
                 (Deferred: 451 4.2.1 mailbox temporarily disabled: paond.tndt)
                                         <tnsharma@yahoo.com>
                                         <tama@yahoo.com>
                                         <harma@yahoo.com>
q33BDrP9007220    50153 Tue Apr  3 16:43 <mohitnegi@yahoo.com>
             (Deferred: 451 4.2.1 mailbox temporarily disabled: paond.tndt)
                                     <tarunrma@yahoo.com>
                                     <taarma@yahoo.com>
                                     <tsharma@yahoo.com>
```

Also, read [Parsing the file perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10876911/1030675) here on StackOverflow - posted by your colleague or classmate maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understood your question, taking a shot nevertheless.

Inside your while loop, after the first regex, store the email address in a variable.
e.g. `my $addressList = $1;` and set a temp variable my `$temp = 1;`. 
Later you can do a `if ($temp)` and if the next line is matching your regex you keep appending to the $addressList variable until the marker (q33BDrP9007220) is hit.

HTH

Comment: Thanks user1441609
I am already saving emailadress in $rf_id,but if i search for the pattern and print its next line it will never give me a result since it will always go to first loop and look for it validity

Comment: In that case you should probably rephrase the question better, can you expand upon what you are trying to do. And maybe illustrate it with an example of what your expected output is?

Comment: Btw, you should also mention what this means? `next unless \w{14})/ % 2;` and why are you reading the whole file as a scalar again within the while loop?

Comment: i am reading whole file into scalar coz i want 3rd line from matched pattern and that 3rd line pattern should check for validity of consecutive line with same pattern as 3rd line

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would go

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file="input_file.txt";

open (FILE,"<$file") or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my $contents = do { local $/; <FILE> };

my @arr=split('q33BDrP9007220', $contents);

foreach my $ele(@arr)
{

    $ele =~ s/([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})//;

    $ele =~ s/.*?([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})/$1 ,/sg;

    print $ele;

}
```

You can change the regex `([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})` for email address with your own.